# Laptop not charging while plugged

Tags: windows-10, laptop

Hi on my Asus laptop F751L and Windows 10 home edition. I have problem having charger plugged in and still it is disscharging. After battery run out I can try to plug out and plug in charger again and I am able to turn on laptop after a while.

Comment: Looks like your charger is not able to provide enough power to both charge the battery and power the machine. If you can find another charger, try to swap to confirm the issue. But IMHO this should be taken care of by the warranty.

Comment: Use the warranty and get a replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that is very unlikely, personally I'd say it's the charger, but if you have warranty just claim your warranty

@DavidPostill What is the reason to delete a comment that actually tries to narrow down the problem and help people? Do we really need a +50 rep to be able to provide the obvious and useless comments?
Using the warranty is something I assume OP could've come up with him- or herself

Comment: "What is the reason to delete a comment that actually tries to narrow down the problem and help people?" - *You submitted an answer not a comment.*  "Do we really need a +50 rep to be able to provide the obvious and useless comments?" - *If your comment is useless then you shouldn't be submitting it.*  "Using the warranty is something I assume OP could've come up with him- or herself" - *You would be shocked, people have asked questions that were solved, by simply rebooting their machine (because they didn't try it before asking the question).*

Comment: “What is the reason to delete a comment”. It wasn’t a comment, it was an answer. Super User is not a forum but a Q/A site. Answers are supposed to be self-contained and answer the question in its entirety. To ask for clarification, earn some more rep so you can comment on questions.

Comment: @Agterbosch - You should remove the commentary from this answer.  The first sentence in this answer, does answer the question, but this answer is unlikely to be well accepted due to the commentary that exists within it.  If you have a question about how the community works, a question at [meta.superuser.com](https://meta.superuser.com/) instead of making a comment in your answer.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't care if it's well accepted, I'm on this forum to help people and be helped, but this place feels more like a boardingschool than a place where you can help eachother, should we just assume OP is an idiot? Because I refuse to do that, I want to help him first, and THEN if all else fails, suggest the obvious which is most likely not the reason he came here in the first place

Comment: You do understand we are not a forum, right?.  So submitting your comments, outside of the comment section, is not acceptable behavior.  My suggestion is not unreasonable, remove the commentary directed towards @DavidPostill, and move on to the question you know the answer to.

Comment: Not sure what was deleted. Someone removed answer . But anyway If I dont have warranty I will try to get me new charger and will see. I thought it is SW. Thx

Comment: Charger seems to solve it